# Joomla include database functions

Tags: php, database, function, joomla, include

I'm using Joomla 1.5. I have created a custom component that pulls data out of the database perfectly. I initialize the database in my main component file like this:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
```

The problem is that I have a jQuery autocomplete plugin on my component page that makes calls to a PHP file from my component folder. That PHP file searches the database for matching results but I can't do the query because I can't call `$db =& JFactory::getDBO();` because this is a custom PHP page and I can't access these functions without any references.

Can anybody help me to call Joomla functions in my custom file ?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used Joomla, but there look to be several options for including a php file in a Joomla file. The solution might be to create a new Joomla file to replace the custom php file, but then just include the php file that already exists.

Comment: I know how to include a PHP file into Joomla, I just don't know what and how to include so that I have access to JFactory and functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend not calling a separate PHP file and instead using the `raw` view format in your component. To do this, create a view in your component for the data that jQuery will be pulling. For discussion, we'll call this view `autocomplete`. Set up the `autocomplete` view as you would any other, only using `view.raw.php` in place of `view.html.php`. Then in your JavaScript, call `index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&view=autocomplete&format=raw`. This HTTP call will ONLY return what you output in your view.

If you absolutely must run an external PHP file, take a look at creating a stand-alone application using the Joomla! Framework: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_stand-alone_application_using_the_Joomla%21_Framework This is enough code to pull in `JFactory` and the database connection. But only use this if you really need to: otherwise, you are just creating another entry point into the Joomla! application that you will have to maintain and secure.

You may find Louis Landry's post on doing JSON helpful: http://groups.google.com/group/joomla-dev-cms/browse_thread/thread/5ac0b49c0f458b1a

I also blogged about this topic recently: http://www.designvsdevelop.com/the-way-not-to-do-javascript-in-joomla/

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the JLoader class to include external PHP files and classes to joomla.

```
        

JLoader::register( 'classname', dirname(__FILE__).DS.'classfoldername'.DS.'classfile.php');
```

This would include the class and make it ready for use:

```
$theClass = new classname();
```