# Dependent Dropdown inside Joomla

Tags: ajax, drop-down-menu, joomla

I was trying to implement the Ajax method for deploying dependent drop down select boxes inside Joomla. The Problem is that if you call an ajaxRequest to run a php with the query that populates the second drop down depending on the result of the first, this is out of the joomla framework and you can't use anything from the joomla functions.

So I need to copy into the new file all the details of my dbase login + to write down the html+php to populate the options. I was thinking whether there is an easier solution to this problem. Maybe the Joomla framework supports something like this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249085/joomla-include-database-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you create a view /ajax/
http://mysite.com/index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=ajax&format=raw

Comment: would you be kind enough to share with us a few more lines of your thought? :) 
It looks like an interesting approach but I need more info on that.

Comment: @kernel I actually never used the method just google: jooml format raw